# Inertia and related quantities

Tags: inertial-frames, moment-of-inertia, inertia

I wanted to know what is a frame of inertai? Specifically, what does it mean by a frame? I know that inertia is the restistance to motion of a mass, a larger mass resists motion more than a smaller mass, and after some research I couldn't find an explanantion which I understood.

Furthermore, on a similar note, the moment on of inertia or the second moment of area is a quantity that shows how a geometeric shape resists motion, but why does a inot of dimension to the power of 4 represent this, and why is it used in the equation:

T = I x (alpha)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are confusing several different but related terms. The Inertia of an object is its resistance to being accelerated. Then there is the Moment of Inertia, which is an analogous quantity, and tells you how much an object will resist being angularly accelerated (rotated/torqued). An inertial frame is one which is not being acted upon by any external forces. It is a frame of reference which is moving by its inertia alone.

Comment: Second moment of area is how a beam resists bending. Mass moment of inertia (second moment of mass) is how a body resist rotation. Please don't confuse the two as they are used in completely different contexts.

Answer (score 1):

A frame usually refers to a coordinate system that is moving in space. It can translate and rotate, and it is attached to ta rigid body. This way the inertial properties of the body remain fixed on this coordinate frame.

[image: example]

In the example below the reference frame $A$ has origin $\vec{r}_A$, and unit direction vectors $\hat{x}$, $\hat{y}$ and $\hat{z}$.

In this reference frame, the mass moment of inertia $I_{\rm xx}$ about the $\hat{x}$ direction, for example, is fixed as the body moves through space.

A frame also refers to the *extented body* which represents what would happen to the particles of the body if they extended beyond their physical limit and outwards to infinity. So their velocity will increase with distance as the body rotates.

The unit directions of a reference frame define the *rotation matrix* that is used to transform vectors from the local coordinate frame to the world coordinate frame.

$$ \mathbf{R} = \left\{ \matrix{ \hat{x} & \hat{y} & \hat{z} } \right\} $$

Finally, the *inertia tensor* from the reference frame $\mathbf{I}_{A}$ (which is constant with time) is transformed to the world coordinate system (where the rest of the equations are described) by the congruent transformation

$$ \mathbf{I} = \mathbf{R} \, \mathbf{I}_A \mathbf{R}^\top $$

The above is a 3×3 matrix equation, with ${}^\top$ being the transpose operator.